# Calculate the Lebesgue integral $\int_{[0,1]}x^{-3/2}d\lambda(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I want to calculate the Lebesgue integral $\int_{[0,1]}x^{-3/2}d\lambda(x)$.

But like Riemann integration we do not have fundamental theorem of calculus as we have for Riemann integral so that we could say the Lebesgue integral equals $[-2x^{-1/2}]_0^1$. So I have only one candidate to check which is the improper Riemann integral $\int_0^1 x^{-3/2}dx=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0+}\int_{\epsilon}^1x^{-3/2}dx$. Here this limit equals to $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0+}(-2+\frac{2}{\sqrt \epsilon})=+\infty$.

So what can I conclude from here? Does the function $x^{-3/2}\in L^1([0,1])$ or not? I am confused. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Your argument is fine and it proves that the integral is $\infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm But how?How do I show that the Lebesgue integral equals to the improper Riemann integral?

Comment: Your integrand is non-negative, so restricting the domain of integration gives you a lower bound on the Lebesgue integral, right?

Comment: On $(\epsilon, 1)$ the two integrals coincide. Taking limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ is justified by Montone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @geetha290krm I think I got your point.You are saying that if $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small then there exist $N_{\epsilon}$ such that $N_\epsilon\to \infty$ as $\epsilon\to 0$ and $\frac{1}{N_\epsilon+1}\leq \epsilon\leq \frac{1}{N_\epsilon}$.So we have $\int_{\frac{1}{N_\epsilon+1}}^1f(x)dx= \int_{[\frac{1}{N_\epsilon+1},1]}f(x)d\lambda(x)\leq \int_{[\epsilon,1]} f(x)d\lambda(x)\leq \int_{[\frac{1}{N_\epsilon},1]}f(x)d\lambda(x)=\int_{\frac{1}{N_\epsilon}}^1f(x)dx$.

Comment: But why is it so that $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0+}\int_{[\epsilon,1]}=\int_{[0,1]}$

Comment: Characteristic function of the interval $[\epsilon ,1 ]$ increases to the Characteristic function of $(0,1]$ as $\epsilon$ decreases to $0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm So what?Please give a complete reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments,I am posting an answer to this question.Let, $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^{-3/2},\text{ if } 0<x\leq 1\\ 0,\text{ if } x=0\end{cases}$ which is measurable .Now consider the sequence of measurable functions $f_n(x)=\begin{cases} x^{-3/2},\text{ if } \frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq 1\\ 0,\text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$.Clearly $0\leq f_n\leq f_{n+1}$ and $f_n\to f$ pointwise.So,we can apply monotone convergence theorem  and get, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{[0,1]} f_n(x)d\lambda(x)=\int_{[0,1]}f(x)d\lambda(x)\implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{[\frac{1}{n},1]}f(x)d\lambda(x)=\int_{[0,1]}f(x)d\lambda(x)$$\implies +\infty=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{1/n}^1x^{-3/2}dx=\int_{[0,1]}f(x)d\lambda(x)$. So,$f(x)\notin L^1([0,1])$.